# Responsive Background Image offers theme code for paragraphs, but I need it in taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Responsive Background Image module offers theme code for paragraphs, but I need it in taxonomy. Taxonomy is a little different in that it is an array inside of an array. How do I change this code to work with Taxonomy instead of Paragraphs?

```
use Drupal\responsive_background_image\ResponsiveBackgroundImage;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_TEMPLATE().
 *
 * Preprocess paragraph.html.twig.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph(&$vars) {
  $paragraph = $vars['paragraph'];
  $paragraph_type = $paragraph->bundle();

  // Add a unique class based on entity ID to all Paragraphs.
  // Ideally we should have a unique CSS selector with which to generate the media queries.
  // Without a unique selector, you will not be able to have more than one instance
  // of the Hero Paragraph on the same page with different background images on each.
  $paragraph_id = $paragraph->id();
  $css_class = 'paragraph--id--' . $paragraph_id;
  $vars['attributes']['class'][] = $css_class;

  switch ($paragraph_type) {

    // Hero Paragraph.
    case 'hero':
      // Make sure the image field is not empty.
      if (!empty($paragraph->get('field_hero_background_image')
        ->getValue()[0]['target_id'])) {
        
        // Construct a CSS selector string that points to the element on which a background image will be added. 
        // In this example, it is assumed that within my Paragraph template there is a div with the class 'hero__image'. Note that we do not have to render the background image in the template itself.
        $css_selector = '.' . $css_class . ' .hero__image';

        // Here we call the method to generate media queries.
        // We pass in the CSS selector string as described above.
        // We pass in the entity object.
        // We pass in the machine name of the image/media image field.
        // We pass in the machine name of the Responsive Image Style. 
        // In this example, I have a Responsive Image Style called 'hero_paragraph'.
        $style_tag = ResponsiveBackgroundImage::generateMediaQueries($css_selector, $paragraph, 'field_hero_background_image', 'hero_paragraph');

        // We then check if the media queries were properly generated and attach them to the HTML head.
        if ($style_tag) {
          $vars['#attached']['html_head'][] = $style_tag;
        }
      }

      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This is a bug report or support request to a third-party project hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and must be reported in its issue queue to track issues in a single place, not here.